# Why do we define the set of natural numbers as follows?

Tags: set-theory

> Could someone explain why we define the set of natural numbers as follows:
>
> Let $X=\{J\in \mathcal{P}(I) : (\emptyset\in J)\wedge(\forall x\in J,x \;\cup\{x\}\in J)\},$ where $I$ is the set guaranteed by the axiom of infinity. Then $X$ is a set by the power set axiom, axiom of infinity, and axiom of separation. Also, $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}=\bigcap_{x\in X} x$ is a set by separation (or by pairing, union, and separation) and so $(\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\})\backslash\{0\}$ is a set by separation.

Is the following incorrect:

Let $X=\{J\in I : (\emptyset\in J)\wedge(\forall x\in J,x \;\cup\{x\}\in J\},$ where $I$ is the set defined by the axiom of infinity. Then $X$ is a set by the axiom of infinity, and axiom of separation. Also, $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}=\bigcap_{x\in X} x$ is a set by separation (or by pairing, union, and separation) and so $(\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\})\backslash\{0\}$ is a set by separation.

> Do we have to use $\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ as we do not yet know that $\mathbb{N}$ is a set? Also, why do we have to use the power set of the infinite set $I$?
> Thanks for your insight!

Comment: What is $I$? Also, in your definition of X, don't you mean $x \cup \{x\} \in J$?

Comment: yes that was a typo. Sorry about that. Also I is the infinite set

Comment: I assume that $I$ is an inductive set as guaranteed to exist by **Inf**.  Wouldn't your $X$ potentiually turn out to be much larger than desired? E.g., $I$ could be a very large ordinal and you would only remove all limit ordinals from it. Moreover, $\{\emptyset\}\in X$, so your $\Bbb N$ would be pretty small

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I defined $I$ but the previous editor deleted my edit. Also, are you talking about the second version of $\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want $\Bbb N_0$ to be inductive, i.e., contain the number $0$ (i.e., the set $\emptyset$) and be closed under the successor operation, i.e., if $n\in\Bbb N_0$ then also $S(n)\in\Bbb N$, i.e., if $x\in \Bbb N_0$ then also $x\cup\{x\}\in \Bbb N_0$.
The set $I$ that is guaranteed to exist by **Inf** (but is not unique) has this properties. What disturbs us is that it may be too big - we want the smallest inductive set.

What follows is a standard construction: If $\Phi$ is a property such that the intersection of arbitrarily many (but at least one) sets with property $\Phi$ again has property $\Phi$, then we can consider the intersection of all subsets of some $U$ that have property $\Phi$
$$\tag1X_0:=\bigcap\{\,X\subseteq U\mid \Phi(X)\,\}.$$
(You can rewrite this in terms of power set and separation etc. so that the axioms used in the construction become clear).

The construction in $(1)$ is defined only if there exists at least one $X\subseteq U$ with $\Phi(X)$, of course. But in that case, the $X_0$ defined this way is clearly *the* smallest subset if $U$ with property $\Phi$: By the assumption that $\Phi$ is inherited by intersections, we see that $\Phi(X_0)$ holds. And by the definition of $\bigcap$, we have $X_0\subseteq X$ for all $X\subseteq U$ with property $\Phi$.

This is what has done in your textbook (though for some reason they seem to want to expell $0$ from $\Bbb N$) with $\Phi$ standing for the property of being inductive, i.e., 
$$\Phi(x)\equiv \emptyset\in X\land \forall y\colon y\in x\to y\cup\{y\}\in x .$$
What is needed in the end is not only that $\Bbb N$ is a set by virtue of us only applying suitable axioms - instead, we want $\Bbb N$ to be inductive. This is clear from the above construction as soon as you realize that the arbitrary intersection of inductive sets is indeed inductive: If in $(1)$, $\emptyset\in X$ for all $X$ on the right hand side, then also $\emptyset\in X_0$. And if $x\in X_0$, then $x\in X$ for all $X$ on the right, hence $x\cup\{x\}\in X$ for all $X$ on the right, hence $x\cup\{x\}\in X_0$.

---

You idea does produce a set - but not the set we want and in particular, the result depends on the $I$ we start from. In particular if $I$ is already the smallest inductive set, then none of its elements is inductive, hence your $X$ would be the empty set (and therey, $\bigcap_{x\in X}x$ isn't even defined). With different $I$ your mileage may vary: If $I$ is a larger infinite ordinal, then your $X$ is the set of all infinite elements of $I$ and $\bigcap X$ happens to be what we want. However, with yet other $I$ (think something like $\omega\cup\{a,a\cup\{a\},a\cup\{a\}\cup\{a\cup\{a\}\},\ldots\}$ with some arbitrary $a$ with $\emptyset\in a$), the result is again something totally different.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that the set of natural numbers is the *smallest inductive set* (plus/minus a $0$, depending on your preference).

The axiom of infinity provides us with *some* inductive set, but not necessarily with the smallest. The idea is that intersections of inductive sets is again inductive, so once we have *an* inductive set, here $I$, if $J$ is any other inductive set, then $I\cap J$ is an inductive subset of $I$.

Therefore it is enough to intersect all the inductive subsets of $I$ itself in order to have the *smallest* one. And this is why we use $\mathcal P(I)$, and not $I$ itself.

Comment: But then, @AsafKaragila, which version is correct? the first or the second?

Comment: The first version, of course.

Comment: So let me get this straight. $\mathbb{P}(I)$ contains all the inductive sets of $I.$ But why is the intersection of inductive sets inductive? You don't have to provide a proof; a simple verbal explanation will suffice.

Comment: Every inductive subset of $I$ is in particular a subset of $I$. So we can separate the inductive ones into $X$. The proof that the intersection of inductive sets is inductive would be a great exercise in understanding the definitions of inductive sets, intersections, and generally what it means for a set to be "closed under a function".